# SQL - DataExplorer Query Top Unsung Users

Tags: sql, stackexchange, dataexplorer

[As previously discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268796/can-we-request-queries-for-the-se-data-explorer-on-meta):

I want to create a Data Explorer query to show the top 100 most unsung users on StackOverflow.

What I mean by top 100 is a list ordered by biggest % of zero accepted answers in descending order.

<sub>This is my first time trying to work with SQL, I was looking into other queries and thought this would be it:</sub>

```
SELECT TOP 100
    u.Id as [User Link],
    count(a.Id) as [Answers],
(select sum(CASE WHEN a.Score = 0 then 1 else 0 end) * 1000 / count(a.Id) / 10.0) as [Percentage]
from
    Users u
    inner join
    Posts q on q.AcceptedAnswerId = u.Id
    inner join
    Posts a
    on a.Id = q.AcceptedAnswerId
where
      a.CommunityOwnedDate is null
      and a.postTypeId = 2
      and u.Reputation > 1000
group by u.Id
order by Percentage DESC
```

Result: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/218910

The result show users have one answer, which isn't true when you check their profiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull this information using Sam Saffron's [The true unsung heros](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229989/the-true-unsung-heros) query. I've modified it slightly to include only the top 100.

```
select top 100 
  X.*, u.Reputation from (
  select a.OwnerUserId [User Link], 
  sum(case when a.Score = 0 then 0 else 1 end) as [Non Zero Score Answers],  
  sum(case when a.Score = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as [Zero Score Answers]
from Posts q
join Posts a on a.Id = q.AcceptedAnswerId 
where a.CommunityOwnedDate is null and a.OwnerUserId is not null
 and a.OwnerUserId <> isnull(q.OwnerUserId,-1)
group by a.OwnerUserId
having sum(case when a.Score = 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 10
) as X 
join Users u on u.Id = [User Link]
order by --[Zero Score Answers] desc, 
([Zero Score Answers]+ 0.0) / ([Zero Score Answers]+ [Non Zero Score Answers]+ 0.0) desc
```

This sorts by the ratio of Zero Score answers to total answers.